# Is there an equivalent for Enumerable.Empty<T> that returns IQueryable?

Tags: linq

It's possible to do the following:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = Enumerable.Empty<Person>();
```

Is there an equivalent for IQueryable...?

```
IQueryable<Person> people = Queryable.Empty<Person>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with this:

```
Enumerable.Empty<Person>().AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have already probably noticed there is no `Queryable.Empty` extension method. You can simulate this by using other extensions methods, such as `Where`:

```
var empty = collection.Where(c => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

calling [AsQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx) on the Empty Enumerable?